# Rejoining as a new actor in Photon Unity Network multiplayer game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, race-condition, photon

I have a turn based game in which I'm trying to implement a rejoin the game feature.

What I do right now is,

1) On disconnect, I open the room and let the player join again. (Player2 disconnects)

2) Once the player rejoins the room I wait for the master(Player 1) to have a fresh turn state in a coroutine.

```
    while (mCurrentState != CurrentState.NewTurn)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    }

    if (IsMasterClient())
        SendLatestData(localID);
```

...

3) The master sends the latest state of the game in an RPC call.

However, here lies a problem. If it were another player's turn to play (Player 3 in this case), they could potentially change the gamestate before the Latest Data RPC is received on the rejoining player's screen due to latency.

If the Latest Data RPC is received after say a "RollDice" RPC I miss out on the data because, the master sends the latest data before it received the "RollDice" RPC on its own screen.

Somehow I feel my approach is wrong and would like another perspective on dealing with this problem.

Comment: I think it's better to store the game state in room properties or cached events. This way you don't rely on Master Client or any other actor for it. So the game state exists as long as the room exists and any joined actor can access it anytime. Also, the question title is misleading in my opinion. And for rejoin, I think it's better to rejoin as the same actor to keep the same actor number (PlayerTtl != 0 and keep the same UserId).

Comment: Thank you! This makes more sense.